# Weird canvas behavior in QT/QML

Tags: qt, canvas, html5-canvas, qml, drawing

I have a strange issue in QML when trying to draw relatively simple graphics.
I'm using PyQt 5 with QT 5.11 and Ubuntu 18.04.
Since the graphics part I'm writing is mostly stationnary (changes about each 1 secs), I found out canvas would be a convenient way to draw graphics without using QPainter. But it's been noting but a nightmare with fonts.

For example, when drawing this simple QML *component*:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: cont_rect

    Button {
        text: "Repaint"
        onClicked: {
            cv.clearcv()
            cv.requestPaint()
        }
    }

    property string cvfont: "13px Ubuntu"

    height: 80
    width: 300

    color: "#132931"

    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        contextType: '2d'

        id: cv
        width:  cont_rect.width
        height: cont_rect.height

        function clearcv() {
            var ctx = cv.context
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
            ctx.fillStyle = "black"
        }


        function drawStateLine() {
            var ctx = (cv.context == null) ? getContext("2d", {alpha: false}) : cv.context
            var x = width/2, y = height - 10
            var txt_angle = -45 * 2*Math.PI / 360

            ctx.save()
            ctx.translate(x,y)
            ctx.rotate(txt_angle)
            ctx.fillStyle = "royalblue"
            ctx.textAlign = "left"
            ctx.font = cvfont
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1
            ctx.fillText("Detected", 0, 0)
            ctx.restore()
        }

        onPaint: {
            drawStateLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with extremely weird graphics behavior.

The FIRST time my component is rendered, I have good looking text:
[image]

Then, when I click my specially crafted button (for the sake of isolating the problem down to a simple component), I have:

[image]

Basically, whenever I am trying to repaint my damn canvas, first clearing it (I also tried ctx.reset(), ctx.fillRect with my background color, etc.), I end up with font rendering that is much less readable and that bothers me.

Is there anyone here who has an idea on how to avoid this?
I don't know if it's useful, but I use a 27in display with 1080p resolution.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tested on Windows with default font (since I have no Ubuntu one) and it always looks the same. Btw, why don't you want to use [Qt Charts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html) instead?

Comment: @folibis I'm curious how Qt charts would be useful? I'm more doing something resembling a timeline than a chart!

Comment: Ah sorry, I've thought you need a graph. Anyway I would preffer a custom item based on QQuickPaintedItem (QPainter) or QQuickItem (OpenGL, but more complicated). In fact you will do the same as with Canvas but significantly faster.

Comment: I don't know QT at all, but where are you setting `cv.context` exactly? It seems to me that in `drawStateLine` you are always require `cv.getContext()` and in `clearcv` always throwing an TypeError isntead of clearing the canvas because `ctx` would be undefined. That's at least what would  happen with the original HTMLCanvasElement.getContext method, since while the returned context does have a `canvas` property, the canvas element will only have a `context` one if you do set it. So it gets dirty because you draw over your previous drawings.